# I'm signing my app with system key but can't obtain system permission

Tags: android, android-source, jar-signing, android-firmware

I want to obtain system permission for my app using system key.
I have signed the app using **testkey.x509.pem** and **testkey.pk8** from 
**/build/target/product/security/**(there are no other keys in the folder) but runtime check shows that my app is not a system app.

For check I use following code

```
/**
 * Match signature of application to identify that if it is signed by system
 * or not.
 * 
 * @param packageName
 *            package of application. Can not be blank.
 * @return <code>true</code> if application is signed by system certificate,
 *         otherwise <code>false</code>
 */
public boolean isSystemApp(String packageName) {
    try {
        // Get packageinfo for target application
        PackageInfo targetPkgInfo = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(
                packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // Get packageinfo for system package
        PackageInfo sys = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(
                "android", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // Match both packageinfo for there signatures
        return (targetPkgInfo != null && targetPkgInfo.signatures != null && sys.signatures[0]
                .equals(targetPkgInfo.signatures[0]));
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?